# How can I select a community AMI in AWS Launch configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling, launch-configuration

While creating a launch configuration, there is no way to select a community AMI? Only marketplace AMIs come on top. Scrolled for long, but still cannot find a community AMI.

[Launch configuration screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiSRZ.png)

[Marketplace AMI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHSYA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than scrolling downwards to find the community AMI you require, you can filter for the community AMI using its AMI ID.

[image: See example of filtering by AMI ID here]

You can get the AMI ID for the specific community AMI from the EC2 launch instance wizard. See [Launching an instance using the Launch Instance Wizard - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-instance.html).

Comment: I tried that option but was trying with partial search. If the full AMI id is given, it comes up. Thanks